# Default constraint not being enforced

Tags: t-sql

Given the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE ControlledSubstances.NationalDrugCode
(
    NationalDrugCodeID INT NOT NULL
    ,NationalDrugCode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,Product VARCHAR(100)
    ,Ingredient VARCHAR(500)
    ,ClassID VARCHAR(50)
    ,Class VARCHAR(50)
    ,DrugEnforcementAgencyClassID VARCHAR(50)
    ,DrugEnforcementAgencyClass VARCHAR(50)
    ,GenericDrug VARCHAR(50)
    ,Form VARCHAR(50)
    ,Drug VARCHAR(50)
    ,StrengthPerUnit NUMERIC(6,2)
    ,UnitOfMeasure VARCHAR(50)
    ,ConversionFactor NUMERIC(4,2)
    ,LongOrShortActing VARCHAR(50)
    ,IsPreventionForStates BIT NOT NULL
)
;

ALTER TABLE ControlledSubstances.NationalDrugCode
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ControlledSubstances_NationalDrugCode PRIMARY KEY (NationalDrugCodeID)
        ,CONSTRAINT DF_ControlledSubstances_NationalDrugCode_IsPreventionForStates DEFAULT 0 FOR IsPreventionForStates
;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_ControlledSubstances_NationalDrugCode_NationalDrugCode ON ControlledSubstances.NationalDrugCode (NationalDrugCode);
```

Why would I be receiving an error on insert for the column I defined as NOT NULL and created a default constraint of 0? I know I can handle the logic in the insert statement to not pass in NULL values, but I use this logic in multiple tables and have never gotten an error before. The error I receive is:

```
 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsPreventionForStates', table 'Staging.ControlledSubstances.NationalDrugCode'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if you explicitly provide `NULL` as its value. The default constraint only kicks in when you *don't supply a value at all*, or when you use the `DEFAULT` keyword:

For example, if `NationalDrugCodeID` and `IsPreventionForStates` were your only two columns in the table (for illustration), this will fail:

```
INSERT INTO NationalDrugCode(NationalDrugCodeID, IsPreventionForStates) VALUES (5, NULL);
```

But either of these would work:

```
INSERT INTO NationalDrugCode(NationalDrugCodeID) VALUES (5);

INSERT INTO NationalDrugCode(NationalDrugCodeID, IsPreventionForStates) VALUES (5, DEFAULT);
```

In the edge case where you need *ALL* columns to have default values inserted, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO NationalDrugCode DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm always using it in your second example and this is the first time that it is the same as your first example. It appears that DEFAULT can't be used with an ISNULL either. Which makes it seem like default constraints are only used in situations when you are completely ignoring the column in a load since they don't apply in updates either?